# Emulate Emacs' "auto-fill-mode"

Tags: autocompletion

According to the Emacs tutorial:

> Type M-x auto-fill-mode  now.  Then insert a line of "asdf "
>      over again until you see it divide into two lines.  You must put in
>      spaces between them because Auto Fill breaks lines only at spaces.

In other words, Emacs will automatically create a new line after a certain threshold.

How do I do the same in Vim, and how can I do this with already written text?

Comment: You want text to wrap? http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11609/205